# Elasticsearch+kibana 6.2 vs Elasticsearch+kibana 7.9

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

What are the main differences between Elasticsearch 6.2 and 7.9? Why someone should consider upgrading Elasticsearch 6.2 to 7.9? Is there any major change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Major" can have different meanings for different people.

The best you can do is to look at the documentation as all new features are listed for each new release.

You can find them here for the ES 6.x releases:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/release-highlights.html

And here for the ES 7.x releases:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/release-highlights.html